# Where is the object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new coming from?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new a rails class? I did search the api.rubyonrails.com and did not find the match.

thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, start a console session and check it out.

Example assuming an ActiveRecord object "state" belongs to an ActiveRecord object "country":

```
$> rails console

$> s = State.new
=> #<State id: nil, code: nil, name: nil, country_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

$> s.class.reflect_on_association(:country).klass.new
=> #<Country id: nil, name: nil, code: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

So, yes, it IS a Rails (ActiveRecord) class.

Comment: the wording (klass) looks odd. Where can I find the detail about it on api.rubyonrails.com? thanks.

Comment: In the example, Country.new creates the exactly same result. What's the benefit to use this long and complex structure to do an easy thing?

Comment: To my knowledge, the use of klass here is accessing the klass variable for the ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection object - if you were to use the word 'class', it would return the type of class (ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection) - but the author wanted the class that the object contained - which in our example was Country.  Since the word 'class' is reserved for creating classes, the word "klass" is used to reference the class being reflected.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no reason to do what the original author has done here unless the association was dynamic.  For instance, putting this line in a loop and passing it different association identifiers to create new instances of each one.